# How to hide multiple labels

Tags: c#, stack, label

I'm doing a stack, I have an input box, every time I input a number that number is inserted into stack, and displayed in a label, I keep adding numbers and labels, then whenever I pop a number, the last created label (representing the stack) needs to disappear and so forth until the stack is empty.

In short, I add a number to the stack, a label is created, I pop a number, the corresponding label disappears.

My problem is that whenever I keep popping numbers, the only labels that disappears is the last one, the other ones do not disappear.

Let's say these are my lables

8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1

I pop 8 7 6 5 ... and the only label that disappear is the last one, number 8

7
6
5
4
3
2
1

Here is the code where I create the labels

```
            if (token != "+" && token != "-" && token != "*" && token != "/")
            {
                problem.push(Convert.ToDouble(token));

                lstbxStack.Items.Add("Pushed: " + token);
                MessageBox.Show("Pushed: " + token);

                lblPush = new Label();
                lblPush.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                lblPush.Location = new Point(290, labelY);
                lblPush.Name = "lblPush";
                lblPush.Size = new Size(100, 20);
                lblPush.Text = token;
                Controls.Add(lblPush);
                lblPush.BringToFront();

                labelY -= 21;
            }
```

And here is where I hide the labels

```
                    operand2 = problem.pop();
                    .
                    .
                    lblPush.Hide();

                    operand1 = problem.pop();
                    .
                    .
                    lblPush.Hide();
```

This is inside a `for` loop and `switch` cases

Thanks

Comment: I sense a data-binding solution here but can't quite flesh it out.

Comment: there is just one label reference so the result is true

Comment: A stack of labels is called a ListBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that after you pop an element out, `lblPush` needs to then refer to the label associated with the *now* top-most item on the stack, so that the *next* pop operation will then hide the correct label. But I don't observe a reassignment of `lblPush` following a "pop" operation, so I assume that it in the current code, this variable *always* refers to the last item *pushed* onto the stack, rather than to the item on the *top* of the stack, which is what I think you need.

One way to do this would be to associate the operands with the labels in the stack itself.

For example:

```
Stack<Tuple<double, Label>> problem = ..

//Push:
double operand = ..
Label label = ..
problem.Push(Tuple.Create(operand, label));

...

//Pop:
var tuple = problem.Pop();
double operand = tuple.Item1;
Label label = tuple.Item2;
label.Hide();
```

You could of course rely on the order of the labels in the `ControlCollection` itself instead, but I wouldn't recommend that. Alternatively, you could come up with something more MVC, but for an isolated issue like this, the `Tuple` solution is fine, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(...).ToList().ForEach(l => l.Hide());
```

In the Where, you should have a condition over the name of the label, but for that you need to give each one a specific name.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend maintaining both a stack of numbers and a stack of `Label` controls, and synchronizing their pushes/pops.  Alternately, you could create a class to contain both the number and the label, and just use one stack - that would greatly reduce the amount of code to maintain.  Something like so:

```
public class NumberLabel
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public Label Label { get; set; }
}

...

var stack = new Stack<NumberLabel>();
```